# Can I put an end to quiet deaths of JavaScript functions? (Does setTimeout swallow exceptions?)

Tags: javascript, firefox

Every now and then some JavaScript function I'm working on would just quit quietly, without anything indicating in any way that something out of the ordinary has occurred.

This is driving me insane. Surely there must be a way to turn on some sort of "I'm a developer" flag so that things like this will throw a big fat **"Something's Wrong!"** message?

Example function:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Entered!');
    foo;
    alert('Exited!');
}, 300);
```

On my Firefox 6, this shows only the first alert. The Error Log remains completely empty. Can I get a more useful behaviour out of Firefox?

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/ will solve your problem nicely

Comment: @Reid more specifically? The Console tab of Firebug remains empty.

Comment: Recently, I also noticed that sometimes the firebug console remained empty. Whereas in chrome, it displayed as expected.

Comment: It seems unlikely that Firefox would just stop without throwing an error. Are you sure you don't have JS errors disabled?

Comment: @Juhanna: It doesn't. But there are indeed some scenarios where the error won't be displayed anywhere (most trivial one being a `try .. catch` block a few levels up of course).

Comment: Three years later, and I've wasted another half an hour on a "throw" that doesn't get logged, ever, anywhere. Once again, this was due to the RightToClick addon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the issue might be this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Exception_logging_in_JavaScript. The new logic that decides which exceptions need to be displayed does have some flaws (particularly when extensions are involved).

You can go to `about:config` and create a boolean preference `dom.report_all_js_exceptions`. This will make sure that a whole lot more exceptions will show up in Error Console - probably more than you would like to see.

**Edit**: There is also an issue that causes Adblock Plus to swallow some errors: [bug 653533](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653533). I'm not sure whether it is covered by the pref I mentioned above.

Comment: Curiously enough, this flag is set to true even though I don't remember setting it.

Comment: Good hint that this could be due to addons! AdBlock wasn't the culprit, but RightToClick somehow messed this up.

Comment: @romkyns: Oh my, looking at its code makes one wonder how *anything* still works when it is enabled.

Comment: Hm, if my timeout calls JQuery.post, whose callback throws an error, *that* error is swallowed unless AdBlock is completely disabled. Not just "disabled everywhere", unfortunately, but actually disabled and restarted. Seems to be exactly the case described in the bug you linked.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a try -> catch around bits of the code to see what crashes?

Take a look at this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp

For example; you can have an alert pop up with the error description.

Comment: Not saying this answer is wrong or anything, but having to splatter a try/catch block all over your code in every single function is not a very useful solution. I think the OP is looking for something, perhaps a setting in Firefox or a global switch in JavaScript, that will turn error reporting on for ALL errors.

Comment: It isn't a useful solution, nope. I'm not saying that. But if you have a piece of code that's breaking and you want to find out why, this will work. You can always remove it again once the code is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Try Chrome's developer in addition to Firebug: Ctrl-Shift-J in Chrome on Windows.